# Allowing access to an Angular 5 app by using routing

Tags: angular, authorization, angular2-routing

**Angular 5**

**Requirement**: A user should only be able to access a page if authorized to do so.

Note: User permissions are retrieved from a server, from which values are being fetched into the application.

**Current implementation**: For each component, within the ngOnInit() method, I check if the user is authorized, using an HTTP request to the server after which I either allow access to a page or use `Router.navigateByUrl` to navigate to an access-denied page.

Is there any way a user can bypass this check? What flaws does this method have?

Comment: Bear in mind that no matter what solution you pick, a user can always bypass any checks on the front end

Comment: Read about angular guards here https://angular.io/guide/router#guards . You are not suppose to check for auth in ngOnInit to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Angular's Router [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) is specifically made for this

A snippet from one of my projects:

**routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, data: {reset:false} },
  { path: 'reset', component: RegisterComponent, data: {reset:true} },
  { path: 'registered/:email/:guid', component: RegisteredComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'cockpit', component: CockpitComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }, etc..
```

**AuthGuardService**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().map(success => {
      if (success === false) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
      return success;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation almost fully loads the component and then realises it has to be destroyed again. such a waste..

Comment: That is out of the scope of your question. Everything mentioned and asked here can be googled anyways.

Comment: This was part of the question - "Is there any way a user can bypass this check?"

Comment: That was about your own implementation.

Comment: Yes. I'm still asking about my own implementation.